# WP Sql query - this has to be correct :-(

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i am trying to do actually very easy SQL query in Wordpress. I do not know why, but this does not work :-(

```
$my_query = ("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'schoolcountry'");
    $vysledek = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);
    foreach ($vysledek as $value){
       echo $value->schoolcountry . ", ";
    }
```

I am in table called wp_usermeta, where are two columns - "meta_key" and "meta_value". And I need to echo the meta_value according to its "meta_key".

So my meta_key is called "schoolcountry" and value should be "CZ"... But this code returns empty nothing ", , , , , ," :-(

Anony knows, what is wrong?

Picture of table structure: [image]

And Picure of var_dump: [image]

Comment: My guess is that either the query never actually ran, possibly due to a connection problem, or it did run, but there is no matching data in your table.  The query itself looks fine to me.

Comment: did you declare `global $wpdb`?

Comment: This was my guess also... but everything runs fine... There has to be something with query logic :-(

Comment: Yup - global $wpdb is declared.

Comment: And what does `var_dump($vysledek)`; (before or after the `foreach`) show?

Comment: I put var_dump($vysledek) after the for each cycle and it printed all objects with corret values... So nothing wrong with that :O

Comment: I uploaded iimages. It may help

Comment: why dont you test a simpler query to see if that works - like "SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE umeta_id= 583" maybe your quotes or use of DISTINCT are problematic.

Comment: Try echo $value->meta_value . ", ";

Comment: This works - meta_value works :-)

Comment: Yes, I also have made that mistake several times myself.

Answer (score 0):

The query itself is fine. The issue is with the way you're trying to display the result.

You're attempting to access the value by its `meta_key` (schoolcountry). The property you're trying to access doesn't exist. You need to use the column name (`meta_value`) instead.

Example:

```
foreach ( $vysledek as $value ) {
    echo $value->meta_value . ", ";
}
```

Another point worth raising is that by appending commas for each value in the loop, you'll have an extra comma on the end.

```
value1, value2, value3,
```

I'd be tempted to use `implode()` to fix that.

```
echo implode( ', ', array_map( function( $v ) {
    return $v->meta_value;
}, $vysledek );
```

Here we're using `array_map` to return a new array containing all of the meta values. Implode will then join them together without the extra comma on the end.